# Teens stranded in eco-system within alien ship, fighting for survival

Tags: story-identification, aliens, spaceship, young-adult

Looking for the name of a book series I read in middle school, 2001-2004 roughly. 
All I can remember about it was that there were a handful of teenagers who somehow ended up on an alien planet that they eventually found out to be a ship. They have to fight for survival against multiple different enemies, I think one of the kids could communicate with part of the ship telepathically. Some of the aliens were either blue or I think even transparent. There really isn't too much to work off of, but I figured someone might know what it is.

Comment: Feel free to post your answer and accept it.

Comment: @katie Lingoes - You should post this as an answer, not add it to the question; ***"It was called Remnants - a book series by K A Applegate"***

Comment: @Richard new users can't post answers to their own questions within 8 hours of posting. See also [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237136/clarify-the-8-hour-delay-self-answer-message-to-discourage-self-answering-with).

Comment: @MrLister - 4 hours to go then :-)

Comment: Answered - Remnants by K. A. Applegate

Comment: Whoah, I was thinking of Animorphs when I read this question. It's so funny that it was actually by Applegate!

Answer (score 7):

Since I don't think Katie is coming back, she realized (and posted in her question) that the series was *[Remnants](https://www.goodreads.com/series/41871-remnants)* by K.A. Applegate.

[image: Cover of first book, "The Mayflower Project"]

From the Wikipedia summary of the series:

> It is the story of what happens to the survivors of a desperate mission to save a handful of human beings after an asteroid collides with the Earth. Eighty people are placed aboard a converted space shuttle using untested "quack" hibernation technology and fired blindly into space hours before all life on Earth is obliterated by a large asteroid called The Rock. They are then picked up by a large, sentient space craft of monumental proportions known as 'Mother' which is inhabited by various races. 'Mother' can manipulate the physical environment within the craft's limits and often does so. Only a few people placed in stasis actually were alive and capable of being reanimated when they reached 'Mother'.

Comment: This officialy qualifies as waiting long enough for something to be fair game.

Comment: As much as anything, it marks the question as having an answer so that it doesn't show up as "unanswered". ^_^

Comment: I was thinking of Animorphs when I read this question. It's so funny that it was actually by Applegate!