# Scifi novel where a boy named Jobs is sent into space in a spaceship to avoid an asteroid

Tags: story-identification, books, hard-sci-fi

There was a science fiction book from my childhood, about a boy named Jobs, who is sent in a spaceship with other people to a new world after earth is hit with an asteroid and destroyed.

I think it was a 10 to 12 part series. There also was an Asian girl named two-face.

Sorry I can't remember more, but I was 5 when I read this book.

Comment: If you type the exact title of this post into Google, this question is the first result and the correct answer is the second.

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/64166/teens-stranded-in-eco-system-within-alien-ship-fighting-for-survival

Answer (score 5):

This is the "[Remnants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remnants_(science_fiction))" series of books written by Katherine Applegate. The first book in the series (of 14 books) was [The Mayflower Project](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/781069.The_Mayflower_Project)

*Per wikipedia*:

> Remnants is a series of science fiction books written by K. A.
>   Applegate between July 2001 and September 2003. It is the story of
>   what happens to the survivors of a desperate mission to save a handful
>   of human beings after an asteroid collides with the Earth. Eighty
>   people are placed aboard a converted space shuttle using untested
>   "quack" hibernation technology and fired blindly into space hours
>   before all life on Earth is obliterated by a large asteroid called The
>   Rock. They are then picked up by a large, sentient space craft of
>   monumental proportions known as 'Mother' which is inhabited by various
>   races. 'Mother' can manipulate the physical environment within the
>   craft's limits and often does so. Only a few people placed in stasis
>   actually were alive and capable of being reanimated when they reached
>   'Mother'.

Notably, the book's main characters are [Jobs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remnants_(science_fiction)#Main_characters) and [2Face](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remnants_(science_fiction)#Main_characters)

Comment: Yeah I remember the series. Did they ever have a conclusion story? I never got to read the final books.

Comment: @JessicaHarris: If you follow the Wikipedia article in Valorum's answer, it has a plot summary for each of the books and it looks like the fourteenth one did wrap things up.