# End of the World, alien planet series

Tags: story-identification, young-adult, science-fiction-genre

There was a book series I read as a kid that started in futuristic, 'end-of-world' times. The kid is driving somewhere in a self-propelled car and a meteor crashes into the earth causing a tsunami that covers the earth. The kid escapes in a pod to outer space, frozen by cryogenics, and lands on an inhabitable planet with just a few others. I remember it was quite graphic for a children's/young adult series/

Comment: Long shot, but K.A. Applegate's Remnants series?

Comment: Actually, yes! I do believe that's it. Thank you so much!

Comment: I'll write up a proper answer when I have time if someone doesn't dig up a duplicate first.

Comment: By a "self-propelled car" you mean something like my 1999 Toyota Corolla, rather than a railway car or a horse-drawn carriage?

Comment: This seems like a good duplicate [Novel where a meteor is about to destroy earth?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/167181/novel-where-a-meteor-is-about-to-destroy-earth)

Comment: @Shawn Please post an answer anyway.

Answer (score 1):

A few details about the initial framing story are off, but this is K.A. Applegate's (Of Animorphs fame) Remnants series. The first book is The Mayflower Project, in which a meteor is about to hit the earth and a few people, mostly kids, are put into an experimental cryo sleep and launched in an old space shuttle.

From [the goodreads description](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/781069.The_Mayflower_Project):

> The end of the world. Not something most people think about. Not something we even expect to ever really happen. But what if you found out an asteroid the size of New Jersey were about to collide with the earth? What would you do? It's the year 2011, and that's the question Jobs is asking himself. The question he asked his family. He certainly didn't expect the answer he got. Didn't expect that in a very short time he and his family would be some of the lucky few selected to board a revamped space shuttle... A shuttle that would leave Earth just before the asteroid destroys it. But there are a couple of catches: The shuttle has no ultimate destination; and all those aboard will be placed in a state of suspended animation---indefinitely. Or at least until the computers find a habitable planet for them to live.

500 years later, the shuttle eventually lands on a huge ship run by an insane AI, not a planet. The survivors encounter aliens and many issues in their struggle to survive. There's lots of violence and body horror in the series.