# 2000s (or earlier) sci-fi novel beginning with a boy who loses his skin

Tags: story-identification, novel

I encountered this book maybe twice when I was very young, maybe 8-9 years old. I remember very few details, but I'd be happy if I could find it again after all these years and get closure. You see, as a kid, the book was scary to me, and I think I was frightened by it. It would be pretty neat to see what I had been scared of.

The book opened with a boy (teenager, maybe?) floating in the air with a laser (or a bunch of lasers) removing all of his skin; he later wakes in a bed with sheets and has a dialogue with his father (maybe?); he learns his father removed his skin as a kind of punishment.

I don't believe I read any further, I was too creeped out from the outset. I don't remember any specific details about the book, such as cover art or size, but I believe the book was probably geared towards young adults. I also believe the book genre was sci-fi (I was big on sci-fi as a kid). This is likely also reflected in the cover art (knowing me, I probably first picked it up because of its sci-fi look).

Comment: About when would this have been?

Comment: @DavidW Perhaps 2007-2008. I think the book is older than that though.

Comment: see also https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/64166/teens-stranded-in-eco-system-within-alien-ship-fighting-for-survival (about the series as a whole)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have the book with me and it's been a long time since I read any of it, so I can't check whether the skin removal occurs in the first chapter or is described as as a punishment, but the book *Mutation,* #5 in the *Remnants* series by K.A. Applegate, (published 2002,) includes a skinless boy named Kubric as a character who is pictured on the cover:

[image: Cover of the book "Mutation", showing a boy in a black shirt with no skin on his face. Text on cover from top to bottom: K.A. Applegate, Remnants, Mutation, Scholastic]

Comment: This *might* be it. The name Applegate rang some old, corroded bells. I wanted to say when I posed the question that the cover was probably *brown*, but I left that out because I didn't think my eight-year-old-self's memory was *that* good. I'll look into it further, see if I can access the relevant chapter. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: I've read some of the book's reviews, and now I'm fairly certain this is it. The reviews hit all the marks, namely, the boy's skin was removed by his dad. I must've missed the part where it was replaced by a transparent layer, but, well, I'm convinced. Thanks again!